# Can I get bower to install packages when there's a version mismatch?

Tags: bower

When I upgrade a version in `bower.json` from say `2.8.1` to `2.8.2` and run `bower install` it doesn't actually install the new version. I can run `bower install -f` but that re-installs all packges.

Can I make bower install only when necesary?

Answer (score 0):

https://bower.io/docs/api/#update

So this could help:

```
bower update --save <package-name>
```